# Update an object every x milliseconds

Tags: java

I'm having a problem. To make a videogame, I have to implement a function called update().

The argument lastCallTime is the last time we called update.

It has to do the following:

1. Calculate the time elapsed since the last call to update.
2. If the time elapsed is more than 20[ms] than ifUpdate = true.
3. And reset the lastUpdated time for every object.

```
private long lastUpdated;               //The last updated time for this object.

public boolean update (long lastCallTime){
    boolean ifUpdate = false;

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long delta = (currentTime - lastCallTime);
    if (delta >= 20){
        //Do something and
        ifUpdate = true;
        lastUpdated = 0;
    }
    return ifUpdate;
}
```

A thread will be calling this method as:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    long lastCallTime;
    int k = 0;

    lastCallTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true){
        //Do something
        boolean ifUpdate = update(lastCallTime);          
    }
}
```

Comment: `lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis()` instrad of `=0`.

Comment: @darijan: Actually, you'd want `lastUpdated = currentTime`, I think.

Comment: You should take a look at the Observer pattern for this. :)

Comment: I dint understand why lastUpdated = 0;
Since you want it to be last updated time

Comment: 1) Is this Swing?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. 4) What is your question?

Comment: My question is: How do I know that 20 ms has passed since the last update. I've tried programming this for like 4 days and I am just unable to do it.

Comment: *"How do I know that 20 ms has passed since the last update."*  Use a Swing `Timer` as mentioned in point 4) of my earlier comment.  If you cannot get it to work, see point 2).  Also, ***Is this Swing?***  I do not ask these questions for my own amusement.  If you are unable to answer them, I cannot help you further.

Comment: No, it's not Swing! I am trying to get this as a test program to later implement it on LWJGL (OpenGL). I've never used Swing. Does this answer your question? I am here to ask questions because I don't know how to do it. I wouldn't be here asking if I was an expert at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote something similar. 
The update method will be called at FPS rate (24 in the example). So that, the time consumed by the updated method need to be calculated (variable `timeDiff`). Also it's checked if the the process was sleep more or less than the indicated (variable `overSleepTime`) and this time will be added/subtracted next cycle.

I hope it helps you

```
long timeDiff, sleepTime;
long afterTime, beforeTime;
long overSleepTime = 0L;

int fps = 24; // the desire FPS
long period = 1000000000L / fps;

while(true) {
  beforeTime = System.nanoTime();

  // your game logic
  update();

  afterTime = System.nanoTime();

  // timeDiff is time needed by the update process
  timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
  sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTime;

  if(sleepTime > 0) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(sleepTime / 1000000L); // sleeptTime is in nano secs and sleep expects millis
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    // checks if the thread has slept more than desired
    overSleepTime = (System.nanoTime() - afterTime) - sleepTime;

  } else {
    // negative sleeptTime means that the system can't be update at the desired rate
    overSleepTime = 0L;
  }
}
```

}